# Is there a way to hide or opt out of the "More By <developer>" list in Apple's App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have several apps in the store, which are basically the same app re-branded for different clients.  Initially, I had released these under several purchased developer accounts, but when the App Store was hacked a while back, I began Transferring ownership of the apps to one account for ease of maintenance.  I contacted Apple to verify that this was still within the spirit of their license and was told that it was fine.

Now, when someone comes to my app store link for a particular app, they see several of the other apps in the "More by " section.  Is there an option to hide this  instead of opening several developer accounts re-submitting paperwork for all of the business accounts?

I looked around on my App Listing for an option, and tried searching for an answer on iTunes Connect but could not find any guidance there.  Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party website and has not relation with software development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot control this feature, neither make Apple do this! You will either have to open a new account or make the current apps unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly that is default feature by Apple for the App Store. There is no way how to hide your other apps.